# indexing rows and columns in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

```
a = np.array(list(range(16).reshape((4,4))
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

Say I want the middle square.  It'd seem reasonable to do this:

```
a[[1,2],[1,2]]
```

but I get this:

```
array([5, 10])
```

This works, but seems inelegant:

```
a[[1,2],:][:,[1,2]]
array([[5, 6],
       [9, 10]])
```

So my questions are:

1. Why is it this way?  What premises are required to make the implemented way sensible?
2. Is there a canonical way to select along more than one index at once?

Comment: When indexing with lists (or actually arrays), the arrays are `broadcast` against each other.  `x[[1,2],[1,2]]` selects the diagonal, points (1,1) and (2,2).  `x[ [[1],[2]], [1,2]]` selects the block.  In MATLAB indexing the block is simpler, but the 'diagonal' is more awkward.

Answer (score 1):

You can do both slicing operations at once instead of creating a view and indexing that again:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(16).reshape((4, 4))

# preferred if possible
print(a[1:3, 1:3])
# [[ 5  6]
#  [ 9 10]]

# otherwise add a second dimension to the first index to make it broadcastable
index1 = np.asarray([1, 2])
index2 = np.asarray([1, 2])
print(a[index1[:, None], index2])
# [[ 5  6]
#  [ 9 10]]
```

Comment: Right, my real use case involves indexing with an array of integers, as in the question.  I've edited my question to reflect

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question then. Will update the answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you can read more details on [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#purely-integer-array-indexing). Basically, when you slice the array by lists/arrays, the arrays will be broadcast and iterate **together**.

In your case, you can do:

```
idx = np.array([1,3])
a[idx,idx[:,None]]
```

Or as in the doc above:

```
a[np.ix_(idx, idx)]
```

Output:

```
array([[ 5, 13],
       [ 7, 15]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use multiple [`np.take`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) to select indices from multiple axes

```
a = np.arange(16).reshape((4, 4))
idx = np.array([1,2])
np.take(np.take(a, idx, axis=1), idx, axis=0)
```

Or (slightly more readable)

```
a.take(idx, axis=1).take(idx, axis=0)
```

Output:

```
array([[ 5,  6],
       [ 9, 10]])
```

`np.take` also allows you to conveniently wrap around out-of-bound indices and such.